# Railo cfdocument saveAsName has no effect

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation, railo, cfdocument

I've created a reporting application on Railo. The last step of this is to allow the users to download their reports. For this, they click on a link which takes them to /download.cfm?report=reportid

The download page is just

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" saveAsName="Report.pdf">
<!-- html for report here -->
</cfdocument>
```

This should be ideally showing a save file dialog with "Report.pdf" in the default file name. However, it still shows "download.cfm"

Any idea what I am overlooking / how to make the save file dialog show "Report.pdf"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manually setting the content disposition header:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=Report.pdf">
```

Comment: Tried that too, doesn't work. Looks like <cfdocument> overrides my previous header

Comment: So, does your response not include this header, or does it include it with the wrong filename?

Comment: Weird, but it does not. I see no disposition header in Firebug. However, it still gives me the savefile dialog as download.cfm. I need it to make it report.pdf

Comment: Well, I just now noticed that my answer had a typo - I had "Report.cfm" instead of "Report.pdf".  Care to see if the new version helps?  It really sounds like all you need is to include this header in the response.

Comment: I DID try that one. I guessed you meant report.pdf. I had tried it before I asked here, so that doesn't work

Comment: Ah well just the disposition heafer worked. Earlier I was sending a content-type and a content-disposition